# How to divide unequal dataframes in R with missing data

Tags: r, dataframe, division, missing-data

I have two data frames  having different dimensions. And want to divide the two dataframe. My original data frames have huge no. of columns over 4000 so, It could be cumbersome to give name of each column. Additionally as depicted below a column in one dataframe might not have the corresponding column in other dataframe. And column name `A.S`, `A` is the name of company and `S` indicates its the price data of company `A` and `A.V` means it is the volume data of company `A`. An important detail my sample size is from 2000-2014. So, If Company a started trading in year 2002 it will have NA for years 2000 and 2001.So, how should I tackle that as well.

```
df1<- S
         Date      A.S B.S  C.S
        01/01/2000  1   10  19
        02/01/2000  2   11  20
        03/01/2000  3   12  21
        04/01/2000  NA  13  22
        05/01/2000  NA  14  23
        06/01/2000  NA  NA  24
        07/01/2000  7   NA  25
        08/01/2000  8   NA  26
        09/01/2000  9   18  27
 The other dataframe 
df2<-V
    Date        A.V B.V
    01/01/2000  12  NA
    02/01/2000  12  NA
    03/01/2000  12  3
    04/01/2000  12  4
    05/01/2000  12  5
    06/01/2000  NA  6
    07/01/2000  NA  7
    08/01/2000  NA  8
    09/01/2000  NA  9
```

And want the desired result as follows. T

```
    df3<-df1/df2
 Date        A      B   C
01/01/2000  0.08    NA  NA
02/01/2000  0.17    NA  NA
03/01/2000  0.25    4   NA
04/01/2000  NA      3   NA
05/01/2000  NA      3   NA
06/01/2000  NA      NA  NA
07/01/2000  NA      NA  NA
08/01/2000  NA      NA  NA
09/01/2000  NA      2   NA
```

Your help is highly appreciated

Comment: Anything you already tried? Why did it not work? And is the Date-column the same for each dataframe?

Comment: I think that you need to (i) convert to matrices, (ii) match up the dates, (iii) divide those columns with the same dates and return NA for any values that already have an NA.  Assuming that I've understood what you want to do.

Comment: @Heroka I tried 'df3 <- cbind(df1[1],round(df1[-1]/df2[-1],1))' and received the Error in Ops.data.frame(df1[-1], df2[-1]) : 
  ‘/’ only defined for equally-sized data frames'

Comment: @user1945827 actually my both dataframes have equal no. of rows i.e. the dates . I would want to ignore division operation on date column and run it on rest. But columns are not same.

Comment: @Heroka yes Date column is same for both dataframes I have equal no. of rows i.e. date

Comment: Is this link of any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368894/matrix-element-division-in-r

Comment: @user1945827 thanks for the link but I want to divide dataframe. I tried to merge the two dataframes,so, that A.S column is next to A.V column but no luck with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this. One way is to homogenize column names using regular expressions (I created 'edit'-dataframes for this, you can off course do this with your original data.

```
#edit column names
df1_edit <- df1
colnames(df1_edit) <- gsub("\\.S","",colnames(df1_edit))

df2_edit <- df2
colnames(df2_edit) <- gsub("\\.V","",colnames(df2_edit))

#create vector of all columns that need to be made, excluding 'Date'
all_cols <- unique(c(colnames(df1_edit)[-1],colnames(df2_edit)[-1]))

#create missing columns
df1_edit[,setdiff(all_cols,colnames(df1_edit))] <- NA
df2_edit[,setdiff(all_cols,colnames(df2_edit))] <- NA

#now divide the dataframes, using all_cols to ensure correct order (and thus division)
res <- cbind(Date=df1_edit$Date, df1_edit[,all_cols]/df2_edit[,all_cols])
> res
        Date          A         B  C
1 01/01/2000 0.08333333 10.000000 NA
2 02/01/2000 0.16666667  5.500000 NA
3 03/01/2000 0.25000000  4.000000 NA
4 04/01/2000 0.33333333  3.250000 NA
5 05/01/2000 0.41666667  2.800000 NA
6 06/01/2000 0.50000000  2.500000 NA
7 07/01/2000 0.58333333  2.285714 NA
8 08/01/2000 0.66666667  2.125000 NA
9 09/01/2000 0.75000000  2.000000 NA
```

Another approach is to do some data-reshaping. First, we turn both dataframes to long and manipulate the 'variable'-variable. Then we merge (all=T generates our NA's), divide and reshape to wide.

```
library(data.table)

df1_l <- melt(setDT(df1),id.var="Date", value.var="value.S")
df1_l$var <-gsub("\\.S","",df1_l$variable)
df2_l <- melt(setDT(df2), id.var="Date",value.var="value.V")
df2_l$var <-gsub("\\.V","",df2_l$variable)

df_merge <- merge(df1_l, df2_l, by=c("Date","var"),all=T)
df_merge$res <- df_merge$value.x/df_merge$value.y

res <- dcast(df_merge, Date~var,value.var="res")

> res
         Date          A         B  C
1: 01/01/2000 0.08333333 10.000000 NA
2: 02/01/2000 0.16666667  5.500000 NA
3: 03/01/2000 0.25000000  4.000000 NA
4: 04/01/2000 0.33333333  3.250000 NA
5: 05/01/2000 0.41666667  2.800000 NA
6: 06/01/2000 0.50000000  2.500000 NA
7: 07/01/2000 0.58333333  2.285714 NA
8: 08/01/2000 0.66666667  2.125000 NA
9: 09/01/2000 0.75000000  2.000000 NA
```

Comment: thank you for your Answer but I made mistake in explaining my case and have updated the post again. 'An important detail my sample size is from 2000-2014. So, If Company a started trading in year 2002 it will have NA for years 2000 and 2001.So, how should I tackle that as well'. Kindly can you look upon that because when I ran this code I received a data frame which add column over 9000

Comment: I don't think that's to do with the dates, but with the pattern of column names. Are they different to the names in your example? The regex will need to be changed then.

Comment: Yes the name of columns are different from the example for example the name of company(the column header) data frame is A.G.L.SJ.INVS...LON..DEAD...13.08.15...TURNOVER.BY.VOLUME  and in other data frame its name is A.G.L.SJ.INVS...LON..DEAD...13.08.15...S. I have 4998 companies in my dataset. So, how should change the regex. And 'colnames (df1_edit) <- gsub("\\.S","",colnames(df1_edit))' worked perfectly and company name became  A.G.L.SJ.INVS...LON..DEAD...13.08.15...

Comment: You need to make the column headers uniform for (almost) any solution to work, the answer by @Parfait shows you how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an [mapply](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/mapply) route using comparison of intersecting and differing columns:

```
# OBTAIN SAME/DIFFERENT COLUMNS USING REGEX FOR SUFFIX
samecols <- intersect(unlist(gsub("\\.*S$", "", names(df1)[2:ncol(df1)])), 
                      unlist(gsub("\\.*TURNOVER.BY.VOLUME$", "", names(df2)[2:ncol(df1)])))

diffcols <- setdiff(unlist(gsub("\\.*S$", "", names(df1))), 
                    unlist(gsub("\\.*TURNOVER.BY.VOLUME$", "", names(df2))))

# DEFINED DIV FUNCTION
divfct <- function(var1, var2){
            return (var1/var2)
          }

# MAPPLY USING DIV FUNCTION
fctresults <- as.data.frame(mapply(divfct, var1=df1[, paste0(samecols, ".S")],
                                   var2=df2[, paste0(samecols, "...TURNOVER.BY.VOLUME")]))

# MONTHLY DATES: 2000-2014
datelist <- lapply(1:12, function(m) {
                         lapply(2000:2014, function(y) paste(m, "1", y, sep="/"))
        })
datedf <- data.frame(Date=unlist(datelist))

# MERGE DATE AND DIV FUNCTION RESULTS
finaldf <- cbind(list(Date = df1[,c("Date")]), fctresults)
finaldf <- merge(datedf, finaldf, by="Date", all=TRUE)
finaldf$Date <- strptime(finaldf$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")     # CONVERT COLUMN TO DATE (POSIXlt)
finaldf <- finaldf[order(finaldf$Date),]               # RE-ORDER BY DATE (POSIXlt)
row.names(finaldf) <- 1:nrow(finaldf)                  # RESET ROW NAMES

for (i in diffcols) {
  finaldf[[i]] <- NA
}

# REMOVE TEMP OBJECTS
rm(i, diffcols, samecols, fctresults, divfct, datedf, datelist)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer actually I missed a detail. And have updated my post, could you please look upon it.

Comment: I ran this code for the updated data frame in my question and it works perfectly and gives exactly the desired dataframe output. But the name of companies  the name of company (the column header) data frame is A.G.L.SJ.INVS...LON..DEAD...13.08.15...TURNOVER.BY.VOLUME and in other data frame its name is A.G.L.SJ.INVS...LON..DEAD...13.08.15...S. I have 4998 companies in my dataset. I have tried a couple of things to change this code but no luck. Could you please guide me how to make changes in finding same columns with the example of name I provided. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is that all one company name including [ellipsis](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&redir_esc=&source=android-browser-type&v=141255454&qsubts=1451748460005&q=ellipsis) `(...)` with just the ending that differs between data frames?

Comment: For dataframe with companies having names ending with S. have different  no of ellipsis before S. (...) but all end with S. Whereas in dataframe where company name ends with TURNOVER.BY.VOLUME have equal no. of ellipsis i.e three in no. before TURNOVER.BY.VOLUME. I hope this is what you were asking.

Comment: See update to handle actual column names and even resolve the monthly dates, 2000-2014.

Comment: Thank you for updating the code. But the thing is in my dataframe the date column is in format 2000-01-05. And both dataframes have exactly the same no. of rows ,so, no need to worry for matching it for date. I have received error that undefined columns received. Could you please help me rename my column names such as A.G.L.SJ.INVS...LON..DEAD...13.08.15...TURNOVER.BY.VOLUME to only A.G.L.SJ.INVS  or even just  A. additionally I have comapny names starting with numeric such as 4IMPRINT GROUP.

Comment: The diff_col created under the code contains all the 4997 companies of the dataframe. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Then, pattern you described is not working. Do **all** columns in first df end with "S" and second with TURNOVER.BY.VOLUME? Please post actual company names. This often happens, SO posters simplify their examples in questions and actual data is quite different.

Comment: I have been able to acquire diff_cols and same cols.  But the code does work to create fctresults and gives error for dataframe.  Which package should I use ? . And about the date they are in 2000-01-05 (Y-m-d) format

Comment: This is all base R (no package). Dates in R should be in Y-m-d format. For string versions of date like in original pattern, use format(): `format(df$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")`.

Comment: I acquired the same and different cols in the two  dataframes by making these changes to the code you provided `samecols <- intersect(unlist(gsub("\\.*S.$", "", names(df1)[2:ncol(df1)])), 
                      unlist(gsub("\\.*TURNOVER.BY.VOLUME$", "", names(df2)[2:ncol(df1)])))` and `diffcols <- setdiff(unlist(gsub("\\.*S.$", "", names(df1))), 
                    unlist(gsub("\\.*TURNOVER.BY.VOLUME$", "", names(df2))))`. Could you please tell me what changes to the rest of the code should I make. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Because when I ran this part of code  `fctresults <- as.data.frame(mapply(divfct, var1=df1[, paste0(samecols, ".S")],
                                   var2=df2[, paste0(samecols, "...TURNOVER.BY.VOLUME")]))` I recieve `Error in `[.data.frame`(df1, , paste0(samecols, "S.")) : 
  undefined columns selected`

Comment: Adjust the `mapply()` `paste0` commands that add the suffix to column names (the reverse of `intersect`/`setdiff` commands where we remove suffix). Play around with adjusting periods before or after `S` and `TURNOVER.BY.VOLUME`. Try removing three dots to one.

Comment: Still no luck. As now I  have the diff cols meaning the ones which are not common between the two dataframes. Is it possible I delete those from both of the frames and make them equal. I tried to do it but the vector made is character based.

Comment: Can you send a Dropbox, OneDrive, or GoogleDrive link of a small sample data subset (5 or so companies)?

Comment: and Parfait how can one send it through Dropbox etc. Thank you!

Comment: Add file to Public Folder and create a link (either on your desktop or via web app). Rows won't matter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99713/discussion-between-aquarius-and-parfait).

Comment: I worked aroud the column header edit. Thank you for your consideration.